# ¿Cómo puedo abrir un formulario de tipo C# en un proyecto de VB.NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net, formularios

Tengo un proyecto creado en VB.NET, pero debo abrir desde ese proyecto un formulario en C#. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: los dos trabajan sobre el framework de .net, lo que debes hacer es agregar la referencia a la dll o referencia al proyecto de visual studio y sólo creas la instancia, te la va a reconocer

Comment: Muchas gracias. Realmente lo conseguí hacer agregando la referencia al proyecto e instanciando el formulario.